# RSync connecting but timing out with no data received

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rsync, repository

I am trying to create a local CentOS mirror, but all of the available rsync sites that I am connecting to are not sending me any data in return.

```
rsync  -aSHP -vvvv --timeout=0 --delete --exclude "local*" --exclude "isos" rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/ .

[client] add_rule(- local*)
[client] add_rule(- isos)
opening tcp connection to ftp.jaist.ac.jp port 873
Connected to ftp.jaist.ac.jp (150.65.7.130)
note: iconv_open("UTF-8", "UTF-8") succeeded.
```

When I use PV I am can determine that there is absolutely no data flowing from the mirror that I am trying to sync with:

```
 195 B 0:06:05 [   0 B/s] [ <=>                                                       ]
```

This is happening with every mirror that I connect to. Is there something that I am possibly missing on my end that could cause the synchronization to hang?

Comment: Try asking for something much smaller, eg a single file `rsync://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/pub/Linux/CentOS/HEADER.html`.

Comment: Do other network protocols work? (Other than HTTP(s) which may be going through a different proxy.) E.g. transferring a file over FTP or with scp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was a firewalling issue. The initial connection is over SSH, which is why I have indication that is connecting, but the RSync server needs to have access to an incoming 873.